# Getting an Error When I replace "=-(" with "="

Tags: string, excel, vba, replace

I am getting a run-time error '1004'

Application-defined or object-defined error

when I try to run the following code

```
    Sub Parenthese_Negative()
'
' Parenthese_Negative Macro
'

'
    If Left(ActiveCell.Formula, 3) = "=-(" Then
        ActiveCell.Formula = Replace(ActiveCell.Formula, "=-(", "=")
        'ActiveCell.Formula = Right(ActiveCell.Formula, Len(ActiveCell.Formula) - 1)
        ActiveCell.Formula = Left(ActiveCell.Formula, Len(ActiveCell.Formula) - 1)
    Else: ActiveCell.Formula = Replace(ActiveCell.Formula, "=", "=-(") & ")"
    End If

    Application.Run "mDOM.DMOnEntry"
End Sub
```

I am just trying to write a macro that check checks if the first three characters are =-( and if they are, gets rid of them and makes it just =

Doing so would allow this macro to toggle back and forth between, for example =a1*b1 and =-(a1*b1). The else works to make it go from =a1*b1  to =-(a1*b1) but the if to take it back to just =a1*b1 is giving me fits.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that Excel is throwing an error because you are handling the formula in two steps and the first step leaves a trailing closing parens. Perhaps if you replace the formula in one single operation it won't have this problem. Sample method below, I haven't tested it though.

```
    Sub Parenthese_Negative()
'
' Parenthese_Negative Macro
'

'
    If Left(ActiveCell.Formula, 3) = "=-(" Then
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & Left(Right(ActiveCell.Formula, Len(ActiveCell.Formula) - 3), Len(ActiveCell.Formula) - 4)
    Else: ActiveCell.Formula = Replace(ActiveCell.Formula, "=", "=-(") & ")"
    End If

    Application.Run "mDOM.DMOnEntry"
End Sub
```